# RMI UnmarshalException

Tags: java, rmi

As I am coding RMI system, I ran into problem with exception at client side

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cs.entity.LectureCourse
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:178)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
    at $Proxy1.getNamedClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.cs.test.ClientCRUD.main(ClientCRUD.java:40)
```

as `com.cs.entity.LectureCourse` is a class that should be downloaded by client at runtime using RMI codebase feature I have checked to make sure

1. the codebase at server VM argument is set correctly and
2. the client VM option -Djava.security.policy= is also correctly set.
3. -Djava.rmi.server.hostname is also used to make sure registry get things correctly

When I ran client and server at same node it works but exception is displayed at client when separate physical machine holds server and client separately.

Does anyone saw this problem before? Please help...

@EJP

Following is the code I used to start RMI registry (inside tomcat 7 contextInitialized)

```
        final String value = "http://192.168.1.11:8080/csl/";
        System.out.println(value);
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase", value);

        registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(8899)
```

and this is the code I used to lookup registry in Client

```
    System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());

    final String HOST = "192.168.1.11";
    final int port = 8899;
    final Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(HOST, port);
```

I think they work correctly but the error frustrates me a lot

I think I find where the problem is. as mentioned before, RMI registry was started at Tomcat 7 contextInitialized method which should be invoked at starting up of the web project. it turns out the same piece of code for RMI server works pretty well if it is in an independent main Application. according to my several tests in different RMI server configurations, I concluded that

1. Tomcat 7 contextInitialized method does something different then ordinary java main program
2. I am not sure but codebase seems work only if the URL(I am using webserver) indicates to a specific jar file rather then directory. (this could be my misunderstanding of the tutorial or something like that)

So the question turns out to be why Tomcat 7 does not start RMI registry differently? I am still working on that

Comment: @Santosh if you are talking about tutorial for RMI codebase feature here is the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/codebase.html#section5

Comment: @Santosh You clearly don't know what the RMI codebase feature is, so please leave the question to those that do. If you have a question of your own, please ask it as such.

Comment: How are you running the Registry? Best way with the codebase feature is to run it inside the server JVM via LocateRegistry.createRegistry(). Otherwise you can run into problems losing the codebase annotation inside the Registry. Otherwise you need to check your codebase server logs to see whether any requests were received: if so, why they were refused; if not, why not.

Comment: @EJP Thats clearly not the case. The OP clearly has missed the point from the link OP mentioned (_that was the intention of knowing the link as I wanted to confirm_). The automatic download of the class in RMI refers to the the **stub** class download(_which in earlier days of RMI, needed to be generated explicitly using `rmic`_) and not the class itself. You would still need the interface classes (_of the object being remoted_) on client side or else the code wont compile at first place.

Comment: @Santosh This was from the tutorial "The java.rmi.server.codebase property value represents one or more URL locations from which these stubs (and any classes needed by the stubs) can be downloaded." I think com.cs.entity.LectureCourse should be those classes needed by stubs

Comment: @EJP I put the updated information to new edition of the question. thank you

Comment: @Korben can you please try with complete jar path for the codebase location ? (_like http://192.168.1.11:8080/csl/yourjarfile.jar_)

Comment: @Santosh, tried with no luck... I am so lost in this problem

Comment: @Santosh You are mistaken about all that. It is not clear at all that the class concerned is the remote interface: you are just assuming it without evidence; and the codebase feature can be used to download *any* class or interface on which the remote stub, whether generated or dynamic, depends, whether directly or indirectly, *including* the remote interface. I have used it to download entire clients, where the executing program at the client knew nothing more about what it was looking up than that it was Runnable.

Comment: @Korben Good, that's the best way to do it IMHO. What did you find in the codebase server logs?

Comment: @EJP I debugged the coebase Server nothing went wrong there. I am now quite sure the problem is on codebase configuration. but have no clue what exactly is it.

Comment: @Korten what do you mean 'nothing went wrong'? Were there any .class or .jar requests? Were they as expected? Were they responded to with HTTP 200? Are the .class files under that directory? What *is* in that directory?

Comment: Hi EJP I have some clue after whole day's checking and testing, I updated the original post please check for more information. by the way, I said "nothing went wrong" I mean I used IDE to debug server's remote service implementation for error detection, I didn't see any error in that piece of code. thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22880/discussion-between-korben-and-ejp)

Comment: Chat is not convenient. You still haven't answered the question about the codebase server log, after several requests by me. Until you do that you are getting absolutely nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

> Tomcat 7 contextInitialized method does something different then ordinary java main program

Of course it does. But without knowing what specific expectations you have, it is impossible to comment further.

> I am not sure but codebase seems work only if the URL(I am using webserver) indicates to a specific jar file rather then directory. (this could be my misunderstanding of the tutorial or something like that)

It works a lot better because there is only one download, and you don't have to sprinkle .class files all over your codebase server: just deploy one or more JAR files.

If you're expecting RMI to load a JAR file from a directory without being specifically told to do so, it won't. If you don't name a JAR file it will look for .class files.

Comment: there is no any exception at RMI server. I didn't know the JAR file stuff before.

Comment: @Korben For crying out loud. I haven't asked you about exceptions at the RMI server. I've asked you 4-5 times about *logs* at the *codebase* server. The HTTP server that serves the files from the codebase URLs. There won't *be* any exceptions at the RMI server, because *you haven't succeeded in calling it yet.* Surely this is obvious?

Comment: I didn't get you quite well. I forgot to mention, the codebase web server is exactly the server I ran the RMI registration. codebase URL is accessible, no exception is saw in catalina out. RMI call worked if I start RMI registry using another java main outside tomcat

Comment: @Korben I will ask you one more time. What did you find in the server access logs regarding codebase requests? If you can't answer this simple request I will have to vote to close your post as not a real question.